# How to pass context from fragment to helper class

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-authentication

I have 3 fragments in my Activity and i am implementing their interfaces like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FirstFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
    RegisterPageFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
    LoginPageFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
```

when I am trying to create a user from fragment which is RegisterPageFragment,using this code:

```
firebaseHelper.createNewUser(getActivity(), email, password, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void callback() {
                accountCreated();
            }
        });
  //This code is running in a fragment
  //      (RegisterPageFragment)
```

I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException. Because `getActivity()` returns `null`. But the point is, I have a ToastMessage before this code block:

```
ShortCut.displayMessageToast(getActivity(), "You should fill empty fields!");
```

Why don't I get errors from both ToastMessage and firebaseHelper? Because they have the same context..

This situation makes me think that the problem is in mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(). Here is my firebaseHelper.createNewUser() method:

```
     public void createNewUser(final Context context, String email, String password , final Callback callback){
    firebaseAuth = this.getFirebaseAuth();
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener((Activity) context, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        ShortCut.displayMessageToast(context,  "invalid info");
                    }else {
                        ShortCut.displayMessageToast(context, "Account created");
                        callback.callback();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Do you know where is the my fault? Or how can I run this code without error?

Comment: When are you calling `firebaseHelper.createNewUser()` method ?

Comment: @VishalArora I am calling that method when I clicked button from fragment